# Symfony 3.3 Populating a ChoiceType Dropdown from a database table

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to populate a dropdown menu on form from database, The choice labels are coming fine but I am unable to return proper values (Ids) against those options in the dropdown, How to write code for 'choices' in the following?

```
public function newModelAction(Request $request)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('coreBundle:brand')
        ->findAll();


        if (!$product) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product found for id '.$productId
                );
        }

        $model = new model();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($model)
        ->add('brand_id',ChoiceType::class,array(
            'label'=>'Brand Name',
            'choices'=>array($product),
            'choice_label' => function($product, $key, $index) {
            return strtoupper($product->getName());
            },
            ))
        ->add('name',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Model Name'))
        ->add('comment',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Comments'))
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Add Model'))
        ->getForm();


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($model);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->render('coreBundle:layouts:newItem.html.twig',
                array('form'=>$form->createView(),));
        }


        // ... do something, like pass the $product object into a template
        return $this->render('coreBundle:layouts:newModel.html.twig',
            array('form'=>$form->createView(),));

    }
```

Form Image, Choices are populating from Db but does not return Id upon submission

[image]

I am getting following Exception:

> > > An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO model (brand_id, name, image_url, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "ABC", null, "XYZ"]:
> > >       SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'brand_id' cannot be null

Ignore the Image_url being null,

Comment: Still the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first solution : Change ChoiceType by EntityType and pass your model entity to your form so symfony can do the mapping alone

second solution : get the brand_id with form->getData() and set it to your model entity

Comment: ->add('brand_id',EntityType::class,array(
   'label'=>'Brand Name',
   'class' => 'coreBundle:brand',
   'choice_label'=>'name'
   ))
Still same issue